# Writing a Procedure in PostgreSQL 9.1

Tags: sql, postgresql-9.1

I am trying to write a procedure (function) in Postgres 9.1 to just select all data from a view and return it (all columns) so our application can use it.  The intent is to have the application make a call to the procedure whenever it wants the data.  My problem is that I cannot seem to get the syntax right to have it return any data.  I have written procedures in MySQL, SQL Server and Oracle but never in postgres and it is quite different.  Once it works is the best way to call it to just use select "function-name"?  Any help would be appreciated.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fg.get_flight_times()
RETURNS setof record AS
$BODY$
declare times record;
begin
select * into times from fg.fn_dy_dest_dep_arr;
return;
end;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION fg.get_flight_times()
OWNER TO jason;
GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION fg.get_flight_times() TO fltrakr;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside a PL/pgSQL function you need to use RETURN NEXT or RETURN QUERY as documented in the manual:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#AEN54092

User `RETURNS setof record`  is no longer necessary in 9.1, using `returns table` is a lot easier. If you only want to return the result of SELECT statement, you can use SQL as well, which makes the function even easier:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fg.get_flight_times()
    RETURNS table (col1 integer, col2 text, col3 text)
$BODY$
   select col1, col2, col3 from fg.fn_dy_dest_dep_arr;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE sql
VOLATILE
COST 100;
```

Note that in this case, you have to specify the column definition returned by your function at creation time. With that version you just use:

```
select * from fg.get_flight_times();
```

When using `returns setof record` you don't need to specify the columns at creation time, but you will be forced to do so when selecting from the function (which I find more complicated, as this needs to be done *everytime* the function is used):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fg.get_flight_times()
    RETURNS setof record
$BODY$
   select * from fg.fn_dy_dest_dep_arr;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE sql
VOLATILE
COST 100;
```

And this is used like this:

```
select *
from fg.get_flight_times() f(col1 integer, col2 text, col3 text);
```

Much more complicated in my opinion (because the caller needs to know the structure **and** datatypes of the columns)

Do read the manual, everything I have written here is documented there as well (I know it only because I have already read the manual...)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Using the first suggestion you made I get the following error when using select to call it:  query has no destination for result data

Comment: You did remove the `INTO` clause, did you? And you adjusted the column names to match your table?

Comment: Here is the function. I had to add the "as", "begin" and "end" keywords or it would not run 'CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fg.get_flight_times() RETURNS TABLE (fn text, dy text, dest text, dep text, arr text) AS $BODY$ begin select fn, dy, dest, dep, arr from fg.fn_dy_dest_dep_arr; end $BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE COST 100 ROWS 1000; ALTER FUNCTION fg.get_flight_times() OWNER TO jason;'

Comment: You did not look close enough at my example. I did not post a `plpgsql` function, I posted a `sql` function. That's why I said "*you can use SQL, which makes things even easier*"

Comment: nevermind the comment above, could not get the formatting right